# How can i ask grid view to know which cell is active and pass cell's value to my function?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Is cellvaluechanged event suitable for this ? how?

```
void filterDataGridView(DataGridView dgv, string columnName, string filterValue)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[columnName].Value.ToString().Contains(filterValue))
            {
                row.Visible = true;
            }
            else row.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

i need too send cell value that user write it,to filtervalue of my function.how can i do that?

Comment: What do you mean with "which cell is active"?

Comment: it mean current cell like this : this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString()

Comment: but it take an exception of object references no set ...

Comment: i need to use my method but i cant :((((( it should work like this : i write something in one dataGridView and by using this method ,in the secend dataGridView data should be filter! help me please :(((

Answer (score 0):

If you want to react on the user typing text in on of your cells I would recommend CellValidating event.

- You write some text in on of your cells
- Cell_validating occurs
- you call your filter method and you may modify some other dataGrid (in your example hide/show rows on given value)

HTH

Comment: What about CellValueChanged, or CellEndEdit?

Comment: cellValueChanged - may also occur if you change your dataSource. CellEndEdit may be another possibility, but to show any validation errors (e.g. warnings, tooltips) or cancel editing CellValidating looks pretty good to me.